# メタで必須タグと普通のタグの色がほぼ同じで区別が付きにくい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, デザイン

[image: サンプル]

ディスプレイの色味はとくにいじっていません。

Comment: デザイナーに連絡済です。調整できるかどうかを検討した上、解決方法を考えます。